# What are eulers?

Tags: scripting

I am trying to create a function that will get the rotation of every object in the scene and I am getting stuck on this:
`bpy.data.object[i.name].rotation_eulers`
it returns values but for some reason they are not the values I expected.  I think that they are notated with eulers and after googling the topic I have come up with null.  What are eulers and how do I convert them to degrees?